# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 while using header Location

Tags: php, redirect, vps, plesk

So I do have a website hosted on my own server (UpCloud), using Plesk. I'm also using Cloudflare.
Basically I did create multiple directories for my website for different regions of the world(en/fr/de/etc...)
I do have a script like this in my index.php to automatically redirect the people based on their country.

```
<?php
require 'IP2Location.php';

$loc = new IP2Location('databases/IP-COUNTRY.BIN', IP2Location::FILE_IO);
$record = $loc->lookup($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], IP2Location::ALL);

if($record == 'US') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/en');
    exit;
}
?>
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error, the 500. No mater what I've tried, it didn't work. Adding some .httaccess code, adding some code I've found on internet for the Apache & nginx Settings, etc...

Did some of you had the same problem and solved it?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Found a working solution using

```
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
```

Comment: Test this: set your settings in the web server config files, not in a .htaccess. Then restart the web server and try again.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 301 redirect should be set as third parameter to `header()` function

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require 'IP2Location.php';

$loc = new IP2Location('databases/IP-COUNTRY.BIN', IP2Location::FILE_IO);
$record = $loc->lookup($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], IP2Location::ALL);

if($record == 'US') {
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/en', true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Still getting 500...

Comment: I've update my answer and added error reporting. Run script to see the error reason

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution using

```
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
```

Comment: That might solve the problem of identifying a country, but it doesn't address the problem in your question.It's also only good for CloudFlare users.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting that 500 error by some miracle. So it's fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you generated no output before you call `header()`.
Check for whitespace / invisible characters before `<?php`. Check that also in `IP2Location.php`.

Not sure if this is related, but but you could try using only  the "Location" header, not the first line of the HTTP response:

```
if($record == 'US') {
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/en');
    exit;
}
```

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
it says it will use 302 instead of your 301:

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it
> send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT
> (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code
> has already been set.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I already did that, without the "header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');" but it didn't work neither.